# What is the english phrase for "barang bukti" from Indonesia?

Tags: translation

In Indonesia we have a phrase that means "barang bukti"

Barang bukti can be literally translated as good evidence

Of course this is not a good translation into English. In English good means not bad. Here it means goods as in stuffs.

Another is material evidence. However, that's also not a good translation because material in English can also mean significant.

Physical evidence?

Comment: I do not speak Indonesian. But "material evidence" and "physical evidence" both sound promising. Have you considered "real evidence"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_evidence

Answer (score 2):

You can see more [Types of Evidence](https://i-sight.com/resources/15-types-of-evidence-and-how-to-use-them-in-investigation/)

"Physical Evidence" is more appropriate term, in the context you are looking for.

It means evidence that is in the form of a tangible object.